# AlertDialog overflowing in Android L

Tags: android, overflow, android-alertdialog

I have created an alertDialog.  It works perfectly in Android KK and prior versions, but I am getting this display in Android L:

[image: Display in Android L]

The code I am using is:

```
        AlertDialog.Builder B1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        B1.setTitle("Theme");B1.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher); B1.setMessage("Which theme would you like?"); B1.setCancelable(true);
        B1.setPositiveButton("Light", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                themeLight = true;
                setTheme();
                saveSettings();
            }
        });
        B1.setNegativeButton("Dark", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                themeLight = false;
                setTheme();
                saveSettings();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert11 = B1.create();
        alert11.show();
```

I do not wish to use a custom layout.  Any thoughts as to how I can correctly get this displayed?

Thanks.

Comment: Should I really have to do this? The above should just be working right?  why is the padding lost?

Comment: You are probably right... I understand how to resize the AlertDialog window, but how do I change the padding?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue.

The underlying problem was that I had android:fitsSystemWindows set to true in styles.xml

Setting it to false got rid of the problem.  Very interesting.